# Workflow of NLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf

When should I perform preprocessing and matrix creation of text data in NLP, before or after `train_test_split`? Below is my sample code where I have done preprocessing and matrix creation (tfidf) before `train_test_split`. I want to know will there be data leakage?

```
corpus = []

for i in range(0 ,len(data1)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', data1['features'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    review = [stemmer.stem(j) for j in review if not j in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
cv = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 6000)
x = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(data1['label'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 69, 
                                                                                stratify = y)

spam_model = MultinomialNB().fit(train_x, train_y)
pred = spam_model.predict(test_x)
c_matrix = confusion_matrix(test_y, pred)
acc_score = accuracy_score(test_y, pred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) `TfidfVectorizer` class with `max_features` argument keeps only k-best features.

> max_featuresint, default=None
>
> ```
> If not None, build a vocabulary that only consider the top max_features ordered by term frequency across the corpus.
> ```

If you present the class with the test set it would help to select this feature more efficiently and this is the data leakage (This scenario is based on your question but in most of the cases, it can be seen!) .
The safest way in machine learning is to ignore the test set until prediction/evaluation, think of it just like doesn't exist!

**[UPDATED]**
You can see an example from kaggle which uses vectorizer on pre-split datasets [here](https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/75095)!
More on this concept mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267012/difference-between-preprocessing-train-and-test-set-before-and-after-splitting) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/difference-between-train-test-split-before-preprocessing-and-after-preprocessin)!

Comment: Can you provide an example where `TfidfVectorizer` (or any other vectorizer) is done after splitting? Because every example I have seen perform vectorization first and then splits the data.

Comment: Sorry but I want an example specifically where vectorization is done after splitting. I know what data leakage is and why preprocessing should be done after splitting, but when performing vectorization after splitting, I am facing problem. Can you give me some examples where "vectorization" is done after splitting as every example I have seen does vectorization before splitting.

Comment: What about our old friend [ham/spam problem](https://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-multinomial-naive-bayes-vectorization/#3.-Reading-a-text-based-dataset-into-pandas) ;)

Comment: I don't think you get my point. Any kind of NLP problem I have encountered so far does vectorization before train test splitting. I want an example where it is done after splitting.